# Selecting serial port in Qt(Linux)

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I have many serial ports, but i want to select a particular one i.e /dev/ttyUSB0 to send and receive data, how to set port as /dev/ttyUSB0, i don't want user to select from a number of available ports, i just want to use /dev/USB0 only.

Comment: Enumerate all ports using `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts` and check `QSerialPortInfo::portName()` values of each port. I can't test it now but I expect port name to be `/dev/USB0` or something like that. If it is so, you can construct a serial port object using `QSerialPort port("/dev/USB0")`.

Comment: its "/dev/ttyUSB0" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a serial port object using `QSerialPort port("/dev/ttyUSB0")`. This `QSerialPort` constructor accepts port name in the form it's present in `QSerialPortInfo::portName()`. It's not documented that this name is in the `"/dev/ttyUSB0"` form but it appears to be so.